# Can Ethereum 2 (Proof-of-Stake) have orphaned, non-final blocks?

Tags: eth-2.0

The question is in the title. Am wondering whether PoS can have orphaned blocks.

Comment: I'm also seeking the answer, So surprised how few people are asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. Let's say a proposer publishes a block too late, it could create something like this: [image]

The late block would thus not belong to the 'canonical chain', and will not end up finalized.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ethereum 2 can have orphaned blocks. This happens when blocks are rejected by attesting validators, or results in a naturally occurring fork.

See: https://studio.glassnode.com/dashboards/80a0d1ac-d82b-4905-66bb-1ca73c44ff91?&utm_source=cmc_report&utm_medium=cmc_report_01&utm_campaign=cmc_gn_02